# Laravel:5.6 redirecting me user login page on a new gaurd

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

i want to use laravel auth system but for superadmins table.here is my code:

**config/auth.php**

```
 'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'superAdmin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'superadmins',
    ],

    'superAdmin-api' => [
     'driver' => 'token',
     'provider' => 'superadmins',
    ],
],



 'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'superadmins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\superAdmin::class,
    ],
```

**web.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'superadmin','middleware' => 'auth:superAdmin'],function(){

Route::get('/' ,'superAdminController@index')->name('superadmin');
Route::get('/login','Auth\superAdminLoginController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('/login','Auth\superAdminLoginController@login')->name('superAdmin-login');}
```

**In Auth\superAdminLoginController.php**

```
protected $redirectTo = '/superadmin';

 public function showLoginForm()
{

    return view('BackEnd.superAdmin-login');

}
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('superAdmin');
}
 protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    dd($this->gaurd('superAdmin'));

}
```

**superAdminController.php**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:superAdmin');
}
public function index()
{
    return view('BackEnd.home');
}
```

**Model:superAdmin.php**
[superAdmin model code see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R36K.png)

**Problem:**
When superadmin is going to login for access his own dashboard then it is redirecting to the user login page not on the superAdmin pageAny solution please.thanks

Comment: in your web.php just pass the name of your guard in this way Route::group(['middleware' => ['superAdmin']], function () { }

Comment: place your login routes outside of the middleware group. when its within the group you only access it after login.

Comment: It is not working still.@ali